# SQL Insert a selected value based on current column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Now I have these 2 tables:

```
table : user
+----+-------------+------+
| id | shops_theme | name |
+----+-------------+------+

table : shop
+----+------+---------+
| id | link | user_id |
+----+------+---------+
```

User can have multiple shops.

Now all the user's shops have one theme. I want to change it so all the shops can have their own theme.

```
table : user
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+

table : shop
+----+------+---------+-------+
| id | link | user_id | theme |
+----+------+---------+-------+
```

How do I save the current user's shops theme. Can I write a magic SQL for that or I need to write some scripts?

I thought about something like:

1. create the `theme` column on the `shop` table
2. some magic insert SQL that will populate every shop with it's user's shops_theme
3. delete the `shops_theme` from `user`.

I need help with (2) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your step 2   You can use update with join for update existing shop row related  to user

```
update shop 
inner join user on user.id = shop.user_id
set shop.theme  = user.shop_theme
```